# Is it possible to make a localStorage wrapper with TypeScript typed parameters and mapped return values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to construct a TS wrapper for localStorage with a TS schema that defines all the possible values in localStorage. Problem is that I can't figure out how to type the return value so that it's mapped to the approriate type from the schema: for example if I want to call LocalStorage.get("some_number"), I want the return type to be of type number. Is this even possible in TS?

*Keys* -typed parameter value works really well for the input!

type Values = LocalStorageSchema[Keys] returns the union type of the values which is not what I'm looking for.

Also it seems that it's not possible to use the variable *key* in the get function for type narrowing...

I have also looked into generic types: LocalStorage.get(...) but I think that kind of defeats the whole point of typing the return value.

Anyone got ideas for this? Thanks!

```
type LocalStorageSchema = {
  token: string;
  some_string: string;
  some_number: number;
};

type Keys = keyof LocalStorageSchema;
// type Values = LocalStorageSchema[Keys]; ???

export const LocalStorage = {
  get(key: Keys): any {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

    //type ReturnType = ???
    if (data !== null) {
      return data;
    }

    console.error(`localStorage missing object with key ${key}`);
    return null;
  },

  set(key: Keys, value: any) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  },

  remove(key: Keys) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
  },

  clear() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics to return the right type for the key !

```
type LocalStorageSchema = {
    token: string;
    some_string: string;
    some_number: number;
};

type Keys = keyof LocalStorageSchema;

export const LocalStorage = {
    get<T extends Keys>(key: T): LocalStorageSchema[T] | null { // Return type will depend on the key
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

        //type ReturnType = ???
        if (data !== null) {
            return data as LocalStorageSchema[T];
        }

        console.error(`localStorage missing object with key ${key}`);
        return null;
    },

    set<T extends Keys>(key: T, value: LocalStorageSchema[T]) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, value as any);
    },

    remove(key: Keys) {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },

    clear() {
        window.localStorage.clear();
    },
};

const a = LocalStorage.get('token'); // string | null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=21&pln=20&pc=7#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-cqoEHVhtWVjdrTc-mINGTm4Mzr9RMEDSkFhqmXiZWQzWdu11l2ID2+9rGFnLGTKQkFola6PstUAOSsDjr85QG68fi8oZQuhAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic as in [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIYBsDKw4CckHMJoIAWEAtklALxQDeAsAFBRSYDWEAdgFxQDOwWAJYdcAbkbNecUhAD6-ISJ4LhYiX2lyOAV1IAjCFh479h8QwC+5xqEhQA0hBC8qUdiDgAzWIlQZseATEZEjmAPRhLODQAGqo2hAu1PDI6Jg4+IQk5ADajs4AuqJQAPxljIwQAB5g2MBQCHAc-D6p-hnQ1PRMUPjAADwAKlDVwJwAJi7uXq1+6YFZIQB8ABTuPIMAlDwpcwGZwbmDBbTqzI3N9eNIwBTUAO7C43D3AHQovmn7EK99AJJjUhrJybaw9ZgRWzQABKEGA2iwHEG0VcZRKZyggm8K2utygAEJKNQdCgUJtTuDmFAsHCERwoLjQhiLBVKRcpCgfoYsNgVgADD5teb4KCkQS8XiqKBwPQAKwgCHqj2ARDcTigABIaO4LHzQRiafDEVASShzMwLAAaVmSOHAkA8fK8S1QABu8QgPCQHBA5O6VKgjw4zzegr2HVevDhALI9pd7pQCX1PStNupZDgrog9sdTl4foxQZD70+7UCrxppEzEBjQPcyYt1oY6gQnKQWBWBcpRZeJaF31erYg7c75qgqcsYM59SqyVLwp+fRWAHIpDJZCYDFhl6CgA). There are still some errors left to fix. Link how to handle null values. It's up to you, so I didn't fix it.